# How to check and get json object in WP database?

Tags: database, json

I need to check if an option value from database is a json object.

This funtion following cannot work :

```
function isJson( string $str, $is_assoc = true ){
    json_decode( $str, $is_assoc );
    return (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE);
}
```

It´s normal because with an SQL query I got :

```
a:2:{i:3;a:4:{s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:4:"text";s:503:"...}}
```

instead of

```
{ '3' : { 'title' : "", 'text' : "..." }...}}
```

How can I do to check if this data is a json object and to get this data as object ?

Final goal : Reaplace correclty value for json object in the database without breaking serialized data.

Comment: Do you have control of the data? is it prepared by yourself before saving it to database? Did you try unserialize it for further manipulations?

Answer (score 0):

To check if a string from database is like `a:2:{i:3;a:4:{s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:4:"text";s:503:"...}}`, you can use the function `is_serialized()`

To get the data as php array :

```
if(is_serialized($data_as_string)){
    $data_as_array = unserialize( $data_as_string);
}
```